# Combine line text file every 5 lines

Tags: php, file

How can I combine every 5 lines into one=

I have a txt file containing the below data:

```
1
2
3
4
5
a
b
c
d
e
6
7
8
9
0
//...
```

I need the output in another file as:

```
1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e 
6 7 8 9 0
//...
```

Comment: Please at least show your attempt.

Comment: There are countless ways to do it. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen("FILE1.txt", "r");
$lc = 0;
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
    {
        print(rtrim($line));
        if ( !(++$lc % 5) ) print("\n");
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @nick output is 12345 abcde 67890 . not line

Comment: It is so simple a bit of code that it doesn't really need an explanation. I get new lines when I run it.

Comment: i get only one line .not 3 line or more

Comment: your code work .thank. i change print( "\n" ) to print ('<br>') this  work fine make line per line .thank . now how to save output to new txt file ? please help .. thank

Comment: @vallez: $whandle = fopen("FILE1.txt", "w"); will create/truncate a file for writing. Use fwrite( $whandle, ... ) instead of the print statements. Remember to fclose( $whandle ) at the end. Nick